# Iterate over R yaml nodes

Tags: r, loops, yaml

I have a file in yaml woth different nodes, with different attributes.
I would iterate over the nodes and take their attributes.
I wrote this:

```
library(yaml)
file <- yaml.load("c:\\....")
for(i in file){
    print(i$pattern$rows)
}
```

I would print the attribute of the subnode pattern of the i node.

A sort of tree explaination

```
-i
--frequency
--pattern
---rows
---cols
```

If I use i$pattern$rows it says to me:. `" $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors"`
thank you.

Comment: You might want to add a debugging statement so you know which 'file' is throwing the error and then post a minimally replicable example. I suspect you've a 'file' that doesn't match the format you expect.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `yaml.load_file()` instead?

Comment: the problem is not in the loading file.